# How to configure mod_evasive to show HTTP status 429 instead of 403?

Tags: apache-2.4, http-status-code, apache-2.2

Some search engine spiders like Bingbot crawl too rapidly and does not seem to obey robots.txt `crawl-delay` directive. This triggers the DOS defence mechanism in `mod_evasive` to generate HTTP 403 forbidden errors. But showing 403 errors to bots for perfectly valid pages is not ideal and may affect page rank. Is there a way to configure `mod_evasive` to show HTTP status 429 instead of 403?

> 429 Too Many Requests
>
> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").
>
> The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the 
>   condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long to wait before making a new request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you just change the HTTP_FORBIDDEN to HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS in mod_evasive20.c and compile again.

Comment: Looks like that is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I forked mod_evasive and made the response status configurable (along with some other features), check it out: https://github.com/jvdmr/mod_evasive

To configure this, install the new version and add `DOSHTTPStatus 429` to your config (either globally or in the virtualhost you want to protect).